# given the number of elements compute the number of elements of another set.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Given that $n(Y\cup Z) = 20,$ $ n(X\cap Y) = 5$, $n(X\cap Z) = 4,$ $n(X\cap Y\cap Z) = 1$ and $n(X\cup Y\cup Z) =22$, compute $n(X - (Y \cap Z))$.

I wanted to solve that without using any graph, but I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed; I tried it this way:

$n(X-(Y\cap Z)) = n(X) - n(X \cap Y \cap Z) = n(X) - 1\\
n(X\cup Y\cup Z) = n(X) + n(Y\cup Z) - n(X\cap(Y\cup Z))\\
n(X) = n(X\cup Y\cup Z) + n(X\cap(Y\cup Z)) - n(Y\cup Z)
$

but it did not ended much far; then I tried the fact that

$X - Y\cup Z = X\cup Y\cup Z - Y\cup Z$

and got

$n(X - Y\cup Z) = n(X) - n(X \cap (Y\cup Z))\\
=n(X\cup Y\cup Z - Y\cup Z) = n(X\cup Y\cup Z) - n((X\cup Y\cup Z)\cap(Y\cup Z))=n(X\cup Y\cup Z) - n(Y\cup Z)=22 - 20 = 2$

but I have no idea of how to proceed from these; any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Draw a Venn-Euler diagram and write in it all the numbers you know. This should make the problem easier.

$$|X| = (|X\cup Y\cup Z|-|Y\cup Z|)+(|X\cap Y|+|X\cap Z|-|X\cap Y\cap Z|)$$

Comment: this seems to help a lot, ty